# I need to get angle from 0 to 360 degree on python by using atan or atan2 functions

Tags: python, math

i have some point on a circle and need to get angle of these points. I use `math.atan()` or `math.atan2()` functions but the angles are betweeen 0 and 90 or 0 and -90 i know that the `math.atan()` function give me the values which are between pi/2 or -pi/2. as i wrote i need angles from 0 to 360.

**at this point i need a help.
Has anyone any idea about it ?
Is there any way to do this?**

```
deger=int(math.degrees(math.atan2(a2,a1)))
            liste_tan.append(deger)
            liste.append(math.sqrt((a1*a1)+(a2*a2)))
```

and my outputs like these; ( it has to be 90,91,92...270,271,272...359 degrees instead of -1 -2 -3 ...)

> 82
> 82
> 82
> 81
> 81
> 80
> 80
> 80
> 79
> 79
> 78
> 78
> 78
> 77
> 77
> 77
> 76
> 76
> 75
> 75
> 75
> 74
> 74
> 74
> 73
> 73 .......
> 7
> 7
> 6
> 6
> 6
> 5
> 5
> 5
> 4
> 4
> 3
> 3
> 3
> 2
> 2
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> -1
> -1
> -1
> -2
> -2
> -3
> -3
> -3
> -4
> -4
> -5
> -5
> -5
> -6
> -6
> -6
> -7
> -7
> -8
> -8
> -8
> -9
> -9
> -10
> -10
> -10
> -11
> -11
> -12
> -12
> -12
> -13
> -13
> -14
> -14
> -14
> -15
> -15
> -15
> -16
> -16
> -17
> -17
> -17
> -18
> -18
> -19
> -19
> -20
> -20
> -20
> -........
> -74
> -75
> -75
> -75
> -76
> -76
> -77
> -77
> -77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atan2` returns angles in the range `(-π, π]`. This covers the four quadrants. If you want a value in `(0, 2π]`, it suffices to add `2π` to the non-positive angles. For the range `[0, 2π)`, add `2π` to the negative only.

`atan` can only cover two quadrants.

Note that in many cases, you can very well work with `(-π, π]`, adjusting the range is unnecessary

Comment: thanks for your reply, i added 360 not pi or 180 and this is exactly what i want. thanks for your idea, it helped me.

Comment: @fatih_koca: why do you want positive angles ?

Comment: @fatih_koca: easier ?